# How do I assign the elements inside an instance variable of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, instance-variables, assign

```
public class Weapons
{
    private String[] weaponType;
    
    public Weapons()
    {   
        this.weaponType[] = {"Melee", "Range", "Magic"};
    }   

}
```

It's giving me 2 errors.

> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
>
> Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment

How do I properly assign the elements inside the array from an instance variable of arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    this.weaponType[] = {"Melee", "Range", "Magic"};
```

Should be

```
this.weaponType = new String [] {"Melee", "Range", "Magic"};
```

You missed the type while assigning it and you need not to add those `[]` again while assigning.

And if you want to move that assignment to top because of that static data, you can simply write

```
private String[] weaponType ={ "Melee", "Range", "Magic" };
```